# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'" when trying to use matplotlib in Azure

Tags: python, azure, matplotlib, tkinter

I am attempting to use `matplotlib` on a Python script in Azure, using a WebJob on a Web App. I am getting the error below:

[image]

The error is obviously when importing `tkinter`, but based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-python-siteextensions/issues/13), it appears `tkinter` is not available in Azure. This is not a problem for me, as when I use it, I am just creating a PNG, so I believe I don't actually need it.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Can't you install stuff in your server?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean but I have been able to install modules using pip, if that is what you are asking?

Comment: What Version of python are you running? `tkinter` is called `Tkinter` in python 2.

Comment: The version is Python 3.6.4

Comment: And if you change the [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)? Try after the `import matplotlib.pyplot as pl`t with `matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem through this.

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't install tkinter with `sudo apt-get install python-tk`?

I usually have to install the package this way before it will work.

Comment: I get this error: `sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` Is this because I am on Windows? If so, what is the `sudo` equivalent for Windows?

Comment: The python installer for windows includes tkinter by default. Did you install python with the executable from python.org?

Comment: I chose the `Python 3.6.4 x64` option in my Azure Web App's Extensions section

Comment: Also, the link you posted states to copy files from an existing install of python, maybe copy C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\tkinter to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs of your WebJob, you are using Azure WebApp for Windows to run it. Unfortunately, due to the [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of `Azure Web App sandbox`, the job to create a PNG by `matplotlib` will never work for you, even after fix the current issue, because `matplotlib` requires `GDI`.

[image]

So I suggest that you can try to make the same Python script works on Linux and use `crontab` to trigger it, and to write a Dockerfile or build an Docker image for deployment on Azure WebApp for Linux. Please refer to the offical document [`Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) to get start.